# How stringent is Pegasus Airlines' policy on carry-on luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage, backpacks, pegasus-airlines

I'm planning a trip with Pegasus (AMS->SAW->TLV) and was wondering how stringent their cabin/carry-on luggage policy is:

1. Would they call a medium-sized backpack (doesn't stick above your shoulders) as its own carry-on luggage piece, in addition to a carry-on suitcase?
2. Will they mind something like an extra plastic bag in your hands?
3. Will they actually check and measure everything?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it counts as an additional small bag
2. Officially not allowed, but DNATA at AMS is usually quite lax about it
3. They will notice the number of bags, but as for weighing it, unlikely if you make sure to get an A4/mobile boarding pass, and as such avoid the bag drop desk.